# Get length of ogg theora video

Tags: video, ogg

I'm currently playing around with libtheoradec but I cannot find an easy way of finding out the playing time of an ogg theora file. There are several examples in the libtheoradec distribution but none of them shows how to get the length (i.e. playing time in seconds or so) of a theora stream. Is this information not available somewhere in the header or so? Do I really have to read through all pages and obtain the length from the granule pos of the last packet? Is this really the only way?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes the information is not in the Theora header, and you need to get the information from the granulepos of the last packet.

I have some code in the chop-rewrite branch of liboggz for this. The function `oggz_get_duration()` returns a value in seconds, and is used by oggz-chop to provide a Content-Duration HTTP response header:
https://github.com/kfish/liboggz/blob/chop-rewrite/src/liboggz/oggz_seek.c

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I didn't see your question before asking mine: [Is there a way to tell the file size of an .ogg video before it is fully loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333800/is-there-a-way-to-tell-the-file-size-of-an-ogg-video-before-it-is-fully-loaded)

I'm surprised no one answered before, as this would seem to be a good question as ogg video sees more use thanks to HTML5.