# Is there a way to tell the file size of an .ogg video before it is fully loaded?

Tags: html, html5-video, mp4, filesize, ogg

I know one difference between ogg video and mp4 video is that ogg video doesn't have metadata describing the file size, so when an ogg video is loaded, the controls can't show the time remaining until the file has fully loaded. This can be a problem if the ogg video is more than a few minutes long. Is there a way to get this filesize when the page is requested?

(Client-side developer, asking a question that I think has a server-side answer. I welcome suggested edits to this question, if you can think of a way to ask it more specifically.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well although not the most direct, you could try this.

First, set up a .htaccess to transparently grab all .ogv videos and process them with PHP

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.ogv$ ogv.php?file=$1
```

ogv.php

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['file'] . '.ogv';

while ( strpos($file, '..') !== false )
{
    $file = str_replace('..', '', $file);
}

$filesize = filesize($file);

header("Content-Type: video/ogg");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header("Content-Length: {$filesize}");
readfile($file);
exit()
?>
```

HTML:

```
<video src="video.ogv" id="video" controls></video>

<script>
var video_src = document.getElementById('video').src;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', video_src, false);
xhr.send(null);
var size = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Length');
alert(size);
</script>
```

So here's how this system works. Just link a .ogv video like normal but the .htaccess file captures the request first and sends it to ogv.php. The PHP file then specifically sends out a file size header in case the server doesn't automatically. Okay, that still doesn't do you a whole lot of good, right? Well, you can then make an Ajax request for the video and extract the filesize from the HTTP headers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Voted up--like the answer, I think it's on the right track, but not ready to accept. When you say "in case the server doesn't send out a file size header automatically"--does it usually do so? If so, is there a way to read that file size header? Also, when you say "extract the filesize from the HTTP headers"--I think that's what I wanted to do in the first place, but I'm unsure how.

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow with an actual file and se if I can get it to fill in that $filesize data.

Comment: Last comment for now: you say "although not the most direct"--what *is* the most direct? Is there an obvious way that I just don't know about?

Comment: Many servers send out file size headers for images only...not for HTML and video. This is a little hack to do that. And the JavaScript size variable holds the file size in bytes so you can do whatever you want with it.

And finally, no, I can't think of a better way unless you have full access to the server. This is a hack but at least it should work in multiple environments.

Comment: I did try this out on my own; it didn't work, but I think it is on the right track. Here's what's wrong (I think): when the .htaccess file changes the ogg file to be processed as php, it changes the Content-Type to text/html. Even though the php file is trying to set the header to video/ogg, it's already been set.

Comment: I'd like to accept this answer, but I can't get it to work correctly for the reason mentioned above. Were you able to get it to work?

Comment: Accepting, as this is the closest I have gotten, thanks, it was an excellent answer and I learned a lot from it. I think this issue with ogg files not sending filesize metadata will becaome a big issue as HTML 5 <video> becomes more ubiquitous.